# Sort a dictionary depending of some value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
"users": {
    "673336994218377285": {"votes": 5},
    "541388453708038165": {"votes": 1},
    "845444326065700865": {"votes": 9}
}
```

How can I sort a dictionary depending on the "votes" key of the nested dictionary? The dictionary should look like this:

```
"users": {
    "845444326065700865": {"votes": 9},
    "673336994218377285": {"votes": 5},
    "541388453708038165": {"votes": 1}
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) This link should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python (since 3.6) are sorted by their insertion order, so you have to create a new dictionary with the elements inserted in their sorted order:

```
users = {
    "673336994218377285": {"votes": 5},
    "541388453708038165": {"votes": 1},
    "845444326065700865": {"votes": 9}
}

dict(sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['votes'], reverse=True))
```

The `key=lambda x: x[1]['votes']` makes it sort each element according to the 'votes' field of the value of each item.

If you're using an older version of Python then dictionaries will not be sorted, so you'll have to use this same approach with `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.

Comment: A short explanation for the 1 liner solution. The collection we sort is the dict `items`. It is a tuple with 2 slots: 0 -> key, 1 -> value. This is why the `lambda` uses `x[1]['votes']`